# HD USB Camera creates two /dev/videoX

Tags: usb, webcam, camera

When I plug a [HD USB camera](http://www.webcamerausb.com/elp-usb-camera-android-elpusbfhd06hl36-p-187.html), I see it creates two `/dev/videoX` ports:

- One with MJPG and YUYV pixel format output
- One with H264 pixel format output

I want to give a name to the H264 device with an `udev` rule, but I can't get it to work.

I've checked with `udevadm` all the attributes for both `/dev/videoX` ports, and both have exactly the same parameters but the index (one being 0 and the other one being 1).

Is there any other thing I could do?

Thanks

Edit:

The `udev` rule is as follows:

`SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05a3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9422", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="rgb_camera", TAG+="systemd", MODE="0666"`

[Here](https://pastebin.com/2tHHGGC7) the ouput of `lsusb -v`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you [edit]() your post and share the `udev` configuration you tried? Also, the output of `lsusb -v` would help.

Comment: Edited answer with both `udev` and `lsusb -v`